# How to frame this set of linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I have the following set of equations, as an example

$2x + 1y + 2z = A$

$0x + 2y + 2z = A$

$1x + 2y + 1z = A$

I assume this can be rewritten as a matrix? How can I check if a solution exists such that x, y, and z are nonnegative? In this case I don't believe a solution exists but how can I verify it without manually testing values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an [augmented coefficient matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_matrix#Existence_and_number_of_solutions), and obtain row-echelon form (using elementary row operations), to see if a solution exists, and/or if the system is inconsistent. If inconsistent, then no solution exists.

$2x + 1y + 2z = A$

$0x + 2y + 2z = A$

$1x + 2y + 1z = A$

$$
M = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 2 & A \\ 
0 & 2 & 2 & A \\
1 & 2 & 1 & A
\end{pmatrix}
$$

- Subtract 1/2 × (row 1) from row 3
- Multiply row 3 by 2
- Swap row 2 with row 3
- Subtract 2/3 × (row 2) from row 3
- Multiply row 3 by 3
- Subtract 1/3 × (row 3) from row 1
- Subtract 1/3 × (row 2) from row 1
- Divide row 1 by 2
- Divide row 2 by 3
- Divide row 3 by 6

$$\text{Result}:\quad
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & A/6\\
0 & 1 & 0 & A/3\\
0 & 0 & 1 & A/6
\end{pmatrix}
$$

If you row reduce carefully, (and you should attempt this so you can gauge your success in being able to do so), you should obtain the following:

$$x = A/6,\; y = A/3, \; z = A/6$$

So for any given value of A, you will have a unique solution for $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} A/6 \\ A/3 \\ A/6 \end{pmatrix}$.

So long as $A\geq 0$, the solution will be non-negative.

---

For review: see [row echelon form and row operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form).

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but... what???

Comment: What does it mean when it's talking about ranks

Comment: See the link: you make a matrix with the coeffiecients of the variables, adding a right most column which in your case would be a column vector $[A, A, A]$, so you were with a 3\times 4 matrix.

Comment: Can you do this with the example given in the OP?

Comment: Are you familiar with row operations?

Comment: Yes I know how to do that based on the link but I don't know how to check if solutions exist, it's just a rearrangement of the equations to a matrix with the vector attached to it

Comment: After row reducing, the right most values (fourth column) will be solutions...if you get a row of 4 zeros, then infinitely many solutions exist. If you get a row with the first three entries 0, but the fourth entry of the same row not identically zero, then the system of equations has no solution.

Comment: what happens when you reduce these rows in this example?

Comment: Also does it matter that A can be anything? I don't know what A is, just some non-negative value

Comment: A can be anything. But for each value of $A$, there will be a unique solution determined by A.

Comment: How did you row reduce that?

Comment: See the link I added at the bottom of my answer. ;-)

Comment: @Amzoti Thanks for the added info!!!